# Mongo db utf-8 exception

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb

i'm wondering why i'm having troubles when inserting strings in db like `hey hey %80` the `'%80'` still produce an eception :

```
Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'non-utf8 string: hey hey �'
```

what i need to do? :( is %80 not a utf-8; char? :O

js pass the string to the controller:

```
function new_pool_post(_url,_data,_starter){
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:_data,
    dataType:'json',
    url:_url,
    beforeSend:function(){
     $('.ajax-loading').show();
     $(_starter).attr('disabled','disabled');
    },
    error:function(){
        $('.ajax-loading').hide();
        $(_starter).removeAttr('disabled');
    },
    success:function(json){
    $('.ajax-loading').hide();
    $(_starter).removeAttr('disabled');
    if(json){
        $('.pool-append').prepend(json.pool_post);

    }
     }
});
}
```

controller receive data:

```
$id_project = $this->input->post('id_project',true);
               $id_user = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
               $pool_post = $this->input->post('pool_post',true);
```

controller sanitize data :

```
public function xss_clean($str, $is_image = FALSE)
    {
        /*
         * Is the string an array?
         *
         */
        if (is_array($str))
        {
            while (list($key) = each($str))
            {
                $str[$key] = $this->xss_clean($str[$key]);
            }

            return $str;
        }
                /*Remove non utf-8; chars*/

               $str =  htmlspecialchars(urlencode(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/','',$str)));

        /*
         * Remove Invisible Characters
         */
        $str = remove_invisible_characters($str);

        // Validate Entities in URLs
        $str = $this->_validate_entities($str);

        /*
         * URL Decode
         *
         * Just in case stuff like this is submitted:
         *
         * <a href="http://%77%77%77%2E%67%6F%6F%67%6C%65%2E%63%6F%6D">Google</a>
         *
         * Note: Use rawurldecode() so it does not remove plus signs
         *
         */
        $str = rawurldecode($str);

        /*
         * Convert character entities to ASCII
         *
         * This permits our tests below to work reliably.
         * We only convert entities that are within tags since
         * these are the ones that will pose security problems.
         *
         */

        $str = preg_replace_callback("/[a-z]+=([\'\"]).*?\\1/si", array($this, '_convert_attribute'), $str);

        $str = preg_replace_callback("/<\w+.*?(?=>|<|$)/si", array($this, '_decode_entity'), $str);

        /*
         * Remove Invisible Characters Again!
         */
        $str = remove_invisible_characters($str);

        /*
         * Convert all tabs to spaces
         *
         * This prevents strings like this: ja  vascript
         * NOTE: we deal with spaces between characters later.
         * NOTE: preg_replace was found to be amazingly slow here on 
         * large blocks of data, so we use str_replace.
         */

        if (strpos($str, "\t") !== FALSE)
        {
            $str = str_replace("\t", ' ', $str);
        }

        /*
         * Capture converted string for later comparison
         */
        $converted_string = $str;

        // Remove Strings that are never allowed
        $str = $this->_do_never_allowed($str);

        /*
         * Makes PHP tags safe
         *
         * Note: XML tags are inadvertently replaced too:
         *
         * <?xml
         *
         * But it doesn't seem to pose a problem.
         */
        if ($is_image === TRUE)
        {
            // Images have a tendency to have the PHP short opening and 
            // closing tags every so often so we skip those and only 
            // do the long opening tags.
            $str = preg_replace('/<\?(php)/i', "&lt;?\\1", $str);
        }
        else
        {
            $str = str_replace(array('<?', '?'.'>'),  array('&lt;?', '?&gt;'), $str);
        }

        /*
         * Compact any exploded words
         *
         * This corrects words like:  j a v a s c r i p t
         * These words are compacted back to their correct state.
         */
        $words = array(
                'javascript', 'expression', 'vbscript', 'script', 
                'applet', 'alert', 'document', 'write', 'cookie', 'window'
            );

        foreach ($words as $word)
        {
            $temp = '';

            for ($i = 0, $wordlen = strlen($word); $i < $wordlen; $i++)
            {
                $temp .= substr($word, $i, 1)."\s*";
            }

            // We only want to do this when it is followed by a non-word character
            // That way valid stuff like "dealer to" does not become "dealerto"
            $str = preg_replace_callback('#('.substr($temp, 0, -3).')(\W)#is', array($this, '_compact_exploded_words'), $str);
        }

        /*
         * Remove disallowed Javascript in links or img tags
         * We used to do some version comparisons and use of stripos for PHP5, 
         * but it is dog slow compared to these simplified non-capturing 
         * preg_match(), especially if the pattern exists in the string
         */
        do
        {
            $original = $str;

            if (preg_match("/<a/i", $str))
            {
                $str = preg_replace_callback("#<a\s+([^>]*?)(>|$)#si", array($this, '_js_link_removal'), $str);
            }

            if (preg_match("/<img/i", $str))
            {
                $str = preg_replace_callback("#<img\s+([^>]*?)(\s?/?>|$)#si", array($this, '_js_img_removal'), $str);
            }

            if (preg_match("/script/i", $str) OR preg_match("/xss/i", $str))
            {
                $str = preg_replace("#<(/*)(script|xss)(.*?)\>#si", '[removed]', $str);
            }
        }
        while($original != $str);

        unset($original);

        // Remove evil attributes such as style, onclick and xmlns
        $str = $this->_remove_evil_attributes($str, $is_image);

        /*
         * Sanitize naughty HTML elements
         *
         * If a tag containing any of the words in the list
         * below is found, the tag gets converted to entities.
         *
         * So this: <blink>
         * Becomes: &lt;blink&gt;
         */
        $naughty = 'alert|applet|audio|basefont|base|behavior|bgsound|blink|body|embed|expression|form|frameset|frame|head|html|ilayer|iframe|input|isindex|layer|link|meta|object|plaintext|style|script|textarea|title|video|xml|xss';
        $str = preg_replace_callback('#<(/*\s*)('.$naughty.')([^><]*)([><]*)#is', array($this, '_sanitize_naughty_html'), $str);

        /*
         * Sanitize naughty scripting elements
         *
         * Similar to above, only instead of looking for
         * tags it looks for PHP and JavaScript commands
         * that are disallowed.  Rather than removing the
         * code, it simply converts the parenthesis to entities
         * rendering the code un-executable.
         *
         * For example: eval('some code')
         * Becomes:     eval&#40;'some code'&#41;
         */
        $str = preg_replace('#(alert|cmd|passthru|eval|exec|expression|system|fopen|fsockopen|file|file_get_contents|readfile|unlink)(\s*)\((.*?)\)#si', "\\1\\2&#40;\\3&#41;", $str);


        // Final clean up
        // This adds a bit of extra precaution in case
        // something got through the above filters
        $str = $this->_do_never_allowed($str);

        /*
         * Images are Handled in a Special Way
         * - Essentially, we want to know that after all of the character 
         * conversion is done whether any unwanted, likely XSS, code was found.  
         * If not, we return TRUE, as the image is clean.
         * However, if the string post-conversion does not matched the 
         * string post-removal of XSS, then it fails, as there was unwanted XSS 
         * code found and removed/changed during processing.
         */

        if ($is_image === TRUE)
        {
            return ($str == $converted_string) ? TRUE: FALSE;
        }

        log_message('debug', "XSS Filtering completed");
        return $str;
    }
```

controller pass sanitized data to model and model inserts in mongo db:
nothing more ... :)

Comment: Even if you send your queries over uri request and don't encode it properly, `%80` evaluates to ASCII `P`. Post some full snippet please.

Comment: i'm using codeigniter php framework and passing the strings by XHR request in POST method

Comment: definitely should be, the problem lies elsewhere. Try posting the code in question please.

Comment: i posted most of the code, but it's a simple data escape and insert into mongo db by ajax.

Comment: the line    $str =  htmlspecialchars(urlencode(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/','',$str))); in the xss_clean() method was bean added by me, to try removing all utf-8; chars and then after your answer i added the urlencode() and now seems to work with char like '%80'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had related problem

eq

ucfirst  for UTF-8 need use mb_ucfirst('helo','UTF-8');

And i think in your situation problem is with: **substr** need use **mb_substr**

else :

So meybe on the begin iconv convert to iso-8859-1 and on write to db icon to t Utf-8

Comment: uhm think don't understand ... :P can you exaplain better? you have my same problem?

Comment: replace $temp .= substr($word, $i, 1)."\s*";   to mb_substr

Answer (score -1):

To prevent the problem you can use

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

in the top of the php file.
Found the solution in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574318/mongo-utf-8-exception-handling) and worked for me when migrating MySQL DB to MongoDB with latin special chars.