# Mongo utf-8 exception handling

Tags: php, mongodb, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem with inserting data to mongodb.

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name']; // "Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn";
$db->table->insert(
   array('name' => $name)
);
```

This gives mongo exception "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'non-utf8 string:...."

`$name = mb_convert_encoding($_REQUEST['name'], 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');`

Helps to fix the issue. But is there a way to force php to set all incoming data to utf-8, so I won't need to use mb_convert_encoding for each data?

I tried

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
iconv_set_encoding('input_encoding', 'UTF-8');
iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', 'UTF-8');
```

None of those helped.

Even

```
mb_detect_encoding($_REQUEST['title']);
```

gives: 'UTF-8' but mongo exception still occures.

Comment: Watch out [the order for the parameters of `mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mb-convert-encoding.php), you are converting *from* UTF-8 *to* ISO.

Answer (score 2):

If the data is coming from a browser, the browser will send data in same encoding that your page is declared as. But to a public server arbitrary data can come from anywhere, so you should always validate that the incoming data is all well-formed UTF-8 before doing anything. Frameworks like Codeigniter do this.

To declare page encoding, you can use the Content-Type http header:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Note that this only declares encoding, it doesn't convert anything to UTF-8 by itself. To ensure your PHP string literals are UTF-8, you need to save your PHP source files in UTF-8 encoding.

Do not use `mb_detect_encoding`. To see if something is UTF-8:

```
if( !mb_check_encoding($str, "UTF-8"))
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
    die("Malformed UTF-8");
}
```

However according to comments, `mb_check_encoding` is bugged in PHP <5.3:

> The issue whereby mb_check_encoding($string,'UTF-8') falsely returns
>   true for invalid UTF8 byte sequences was resolved somewhere between 
>   PHP 5.2.0 and 5.2.6